# What are the techniques for making recent content relevant in lucene?

Tags: java, lucene

I am implementing a search where recent content needs to be more relevant than older content.  I do not want a filter or range, but want to increase the relevancy of the youngest content.

What are some solutions that have worked?

Comment: It can be done with function queries. There's an example in the [Lucene in Action](http://www.manning.com/hatcher2/) book, page 187. Don't know where there could be a good example online...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If upgrading to [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) is an option for you take a look at [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents).

Comment: It unfortunately isn't.  Any way to replicate the functionality?

Comment: @jon077 Possibly [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724451/boost-fresh-documents-with-lucene) can help you further

Comment: Hmmm... so the idea is set a ground-zero date.. then continually increase the boost from that day forward (now-start)=boost.... thus future documents are always more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could could add separate fields for month and date and make them part of the query. It would mean explicitly building out a date related section of the query, but you could boost year: 2011 and month: 6 over other results. You could explicitly boost however much time is important and use unboosted wildcards for the rest.