# Is Boosting whole documents supported in an AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<T> that utilizes the Reduce feature?

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to boost documents based on how recent they were posted as [discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863739/how-can-you-boost-documents-by-recency-in-ravendb#answer-13866033).

The following index definition works fine creating an index that is populated with Article and Recipe entities.

```cs
public class TestIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Result>
{
    public TestIndex()
    {
        AddMap<Article>(docs => from doc in docs
                                where !doc.IsDeleted
                                select new Result
                                {
                                    Id            = doc.Id,
                                    Title         = doc.Title,
                                    DatePublished = doc.DatePublished
                                }.Boost(doc.DatePublished.Ticks / 1000000f));

        AddMap<Recipe>(docs => from doc in docs
                               where !doc.IsDeleted
                               select new Result
                               {
                                   Id            = doc.Id,
                                   Title         = doc.Title,
                                   DatePublished = doc.DatePublished
                               }.Boost(doc.DatePublished.Ticks / 100000f));
    }

    public override string IndexName
    {
        get { return "Tests/WithBoost"; }
    }
}
```

When I try to add a Reduce to store the documents as a `Result` item the index ceases to generate any results.

```cs
public class TestIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<Result>
{
    public TestIndex()
    {
        AddMap<Article>(docs => from doc in docs
                                where !doc.IsDeleted
                                select new Result
                                {
                                    Id            = doc.Id,
                                    Title         = doc.Title,
                                    DatePublished = doc.DatePublished
                                }.Boost(doc.DatePublished.Ticks / 100000f));

        AddMap<Recipe>(docs => from doc in docs
                               where !doc.IsDeleted
                               select new Result
                               {
                                   Id            = doc.Id,
                                   Title         = doc.Title,
                                   DatePublished = doc.DatePublished
                               }.Boost(doc.DatePublished.Ticks / 100000f));

        Reduce = docs => from doc in docs
                         group doc by doc.Id into g
                         select new Result
                         {
                             Id            = g.First().Id,
                             Title         = g.First().Title,
                             DatePublished = g.First().DatePublished
                         };
    }

    public override string IndexName
    {
        get { return "Tests/WithBoost"; }
    }
}
```

**Is boosting documents supported when using the Reduce feature of `AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<T>`?**

A thought I'm having is that `Boost()` returns a `BoostedValue`, so is the collection being passed to the Reduce  expression actually `IEnumerable<BoostedValue>` instead of `IEnumerable<Result>`, and therefore the Reduce expression cannot be compiled against the input?

Comment: What build are you using? This should work

Comment: Oh, sorry. The Boost will be applied on the last thing, not during the map.
But note that your index make no sense. There is NO need for the reduce

Comment: @AyendeRahien I'm using build 960. How do you mean "on the last thing"? Do you mean in the Reduce, rather than in the Map. How do you mean the index makes no sense? In the actual implementation `Result` has more properties and `Article` and `Recipe` are quite different entities. I need a way of querying them as a single collection and listing them out on the page in a consistent way. The simplicity of `Result` and similarity between `Article` and `Recipe` are for demonstration purposes.

Comment: The reduce you provided doesn't actually do anything, since it groups by the doc id and takes the first (only) item in the group.  Can you provide a more realistic example?  If all you're after is mapping from both `Article` and `Recipe`, you don't need a reduce for that - even if they have other differing fields.

Comment: @MattJohnson So where should the Boost be done, in the `Map<T>()`s? How then do you query the index and get back `Result`s in the order specified by the Boost?

Answer (score 0):

(This answer carried over from the comments in the original post)

If you just want to sort by date published, don't use boost - use `.OrderByDescending(x=> x.DatePublished)`.

If you're just wanting to know how to query on a combined multimap result, you can do that easily like this:

```cs
var results = session.Query<Result, TestIndex>()
                     .Search(x=> x.Title, "whatever")
                     .As<object>()
                     .ToList();

var articles = results.OfType<Article>();
var recipies = results.OfType<Recipe>();
```

I'm assuming you want to search, since you are boosting.  You should also be marking the searchable fields as analyzed, as documented [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/linq-extensions/search).

I'm also assuming you want articles and recipes separated into separate lists.  If you don't, then you can just use the object list directly.  Or if you have some base class or interface that they both use, then you can use that instead of object, as in `.As<IWhatever>()`.